# Show a group is solvable iff quotient by its center is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

> Let $G$ be a group. Prove that
>
> $G$ is solvable $\iff$ $G'$ is solvable $\iff$ $G/Z(G)$ is solvable.

$G'$ is the commutator subgroup.

I've figured out the first of the stated equivalences but don't really know where to start on the second.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is solvable, so is every quotient - see this question:
[Solvable implies quotient group is solvable: Proof check.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911468/solvable-implies-quotient-group-is-solvable-proof-check)
For the converse see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933146/why-if-h%E2%8A%B4g-and-h-is-solvable-and-g-h-is-solvable-then-g-is-also-solvable), with $H=Z(G)$. Or see this one:

[For $G$ a group and $H\unlhd G$, then $G$ is solvable iff $H$ and $G/H$ are solvable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39814/for-g-a-group-and-h-unlhd-g-then-g-is-solvable-iff-h-and-g-h-are-solv)